# Como unir multiples registros en uno solo usando SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Necesito que esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se convierta en esto: (lo edite como imagen usando paint para mostrar como ejemplo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos tendrán siempre el mismo 'serverName', DATE y TIME en común

Comment: traduce tu pregunta pues estas en la versión en español de SO, de otro modo terminará cerrada

Comment: Hola @Ricardo, bienvenido a StackOverflow *en español*. Recomiendo escribir tu respuesta en la lengua de Cervantes, que es lo esperado en este sitio. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es *agrupar* por ciertas columnas. En este caso, por `serverName`, `Date` y `Time`, por ejemplo, esta consulta devolvería un resultado como el que esperas:

```
with
Datos as (
select 16 idse, 'LSTKAG72544' serverName, cast('20180928' as date) [DATE], CAST('17:09:59' as time) [TIME], null SQLBrowser, 'Running' W3SVC, null wscsvc
union all
select 17 idse, 'LSTKAG72544' serverName, cast('20180928' as date) [date], CAST('17:09:59' as time) [time], null SQLBrowser, null W3SVC, 'Running' wscsvc
union all
select 18 idse, 'LSTKAG72544' serverName, cast('20180928' as date) [date], CAST('17:09:59' as time) [time], 'Running' SQLBrowser, null W3SVC, null wscsvc
)
select   min(idse) idse
       , serverName
       , [DATE]
       , [TIME]
       , min(SQLBrowser) SQLBrowser
       , min(W3SVC) W3SVC
       , MIN(wscsvc) wscsvc
  from Datos
 group by serverName, [DATE], [TIME];
```